# Switching from Dropbox to Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, 11.10, dropbox

I have a free Dropbox account which I use about 5-10% of currently. I mostly use it on my Windows 7 work laptop to store my source code backups (pseudo-SVN), and also on my Windows 7 home desktop which I use to store some of my documents which I want to keep safe in case of data loss etc.

I'm just about to upgrade my netbook from 11.04 to 11.10 (clean install). Should I be switching from Dropbox to Ubuntu One? It wouldn't be very difficult to transfer my files across, it's mostly a case of which one is better for me.

I'd like to have my source code and documents available on my netbook and have been using the Ubuntu Dropbox client up until now and have been happy with it, but I know Ubuntu One is more tightly intergrated with the OS.

Which one do you suggest?

Comment: Use both! You don't need to choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used the Ubuntu One service, but it looks like a viable alternative to DropBox. I've used Dropbox for several months now, and I haven't had any issues with it. The only nice thing about Ubuntu One is that is has 5GB free storage. Dropbox you only get 2GB free.

They also offer a Windows7/Vista program for Ubuntu One. It looks very similar to Dropbox. https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to keep them both.

This way, you get redundancy and if one service goes down, you can still have another. You can use symlinks to link content in one-service to another.

Which one you use as a primary service is upto you. Dropbox has higher coverage(although clients are getting done for Ubuntu One as well). Ubuntu One has higher free storage (5gb), but since you already have a dropbox account, you may wish to stick to it.

---

[SpiderOak](http://www.spideroak.com/) is another service you might like. Especially if you want to use this for backups, as it has a special Backup option.

Answer (score 1):

I love the ubuntu one interface and the integration with the operating system, was also contemplating the idea of buying extra storage but unfortunately their products are way expensive that google's storage. Currently I use multiple services to store my important files, especially my 20 GB of pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I have had great experiences with both Dropbox and Ubuntu One, but in the end I have chosen Ubuntu One for one main reason: while both Dropbox and Ubuntu One give you file syncing, Ubuntu One let's you select a folder/file on your computer and have it automatically sync. In other words, you don't need to constantly copy files from your computer to Dropbox/Ubuntu One and vice versa to update your files. I find this extremely useful because when I edit a file on a different computer and later view it on my personal computer, the file is automatically updated on my computer, not just on Dropbox/Ubuntu One. Hope this helps!

Comment: Uhh? I'm pretty sure my Dropbox folders automatically syncs in the same way? I don't think I've ever "manually" had to upload anything to Dropbox.

Comment: Yes, Dropbox does automatically sync. Forgive me for not properly explaining. What I meant was that Ubuntu One, unlike Dropbox, syncs folders native on you computer, not just one pre-specified folder, such as the "Dropbox" folder, which does exist on your computer. For example, Ubuntu comes with the "Documents" folder. I can just right click and select to sync and it syncs; no need to move it to the Ubuntu One/Dropbox folder. NOTE: I am speaking form my experiences with Dropbox, which ended quite a while ago. If Dropbox had added this feature; forgive my lack of keeping up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest and am using both.
They have different advantages and disadvantages, so I take advantage of each's strength's:

I use **UbuntuOne** for a bunch of video's.
  *Advantages of UbuntuOne for this kinda stuff:*
- More than twice as much free space as Dropbox.
- Tightly integrated with Ubuntu, my main OS.
- Still available on Windows machines that I use.
- Currently has a cheaper minimum paid level at $4 a month (20GB), compared to Dropbox - $10 a month (50GB).
- Allows me to pick 'other' folders outside of my standard UbuntuOne folder.

I use **Dropbox** for code, text clips and all the other assorted documents I like access to.
*Advantages of Dropbox for this kinda stuff:*
- Well integrated and works well with gui's on all platforms.
- Easy to set up folder sharing with others.
- Constant Panel notification for activity (UbuntuOne only has pop-ups right now).
- Well known so familiar to and used by more others.

Finally using both also gives me
2GB (dropbox) + 1/2GB (dropbox referral) + 5GB (UbuntuOne) for a total of **7.5 free GB**...